# time complexity of WHERE EXIST in mysql

Tags: mysql, time-complexity

I would like to ask the time complexity of the following query. Is it O(NM) or O(M+N) ? If it's O(MN), could I achieve O(N+M) by using other queires?

Table A, having N row;

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| account     | char(17)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| key         | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| other field |              |      |     |         |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

show create table A:
| A | CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `account` char(17) NOT NULL,
  `key` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Table B, having M row;

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| account     | char(17)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

show create table B:
| B | CREATE TABLE `B` (
  `account` char(17) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Query

```
select count(*) from B where exist (
  select null from A where
    A.account = B.account and A.key != 1234
);
```

Explain

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref       | rows  | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A          | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL      | 13076 |    90.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B          | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 258     | A.account |     1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table A;` and `show create table B;` and `select version();` and `explain select ...rest of your query`

Comment: what percentage of accounts in B appear in A, and vice versa?

Comment: Edited, don't know what to explain though. No fixed percentage overlay, could be 0 to 100%.

Comment: I mean show the output of `explain select count(*) from B where exist (select null from A where A.Account=B.account and A.key != 1234);`.  That will show you the query plan being used.

Comment: Edited already.

Comment: It is reading A, and for each A row checking for a B row.  So O(N). (M will not have any significant effect)